# recording a local webrtc stream on android

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, video-recording

I am using the example native android application (apprtc) to stream video between an android device and a browser. I want to record the local stream on the android device. For clarification the use case will be like:

1-User connects to an android device from his/her browser.

2-Android device starts sending a video stream to the user and records the stream locally at the same time.

I have been googling for the past week with no success. What I have found so far:

-This feature is not implemented yet in webrtc. There is a debate on the video format.

-There is a project named RecordRTC that can do something like that.

RecordRTC seems fine but i need to do this in a native android application like apprtc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may have to sent audio buffers and video frames over websockets to a locally hosted websocketserver. I do believe their are Java WebsocketServers that will allow this, you just may have to jerry rig it slightly for android. [Helpful Tutorial](http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets)

Comment: @bwtrent thanks for the comment. Your solution makes sense but seems like a very hackish one. I will research a bit more.

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is making it all native C++ and using the WebRTC API. From there you have direct access to the decoded RTP streams and can do what you want with them.

Comment: @dogauzun Did u get any solution? Even I too want to do the same. Could u pls share how u did it?

Comment: @Dev sadly, I was not able to find a solution. I moved on to a different project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC on Android using `GLSurfaceView` to display video from a camera (local stream) or from another devices (remote stream). So, to record a local stream you can make it with some project which can record data from `GLSurfaceView` such as gafrika, [Intel media for mobile](https://software.intel.com/en-us/media-for-mobile-support), or everyplay.